# Is there anyway to declare all class to index.d.ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I declaring all class in multiple different files? In my current typings/index.d.ts was

```
declare module 'mymodule'
declare module 'mymodule/myfiles.js'
```

I can import them using these codes

```
import { FirstClass } from "estrajs";
import { SecondClass } from "estrajs/myfiles.js";
```

But I want the second import don't use any of files name at the end like `./myfiles.js`, I just want only use the first import